# How to read dynamic html table rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    function AddRow() {
    $('#myDynamicTable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="itemName"><input type="text" style="width: 300px;"/><td class="itemQty"><input type="text" style="width: 50px;"/></td></td> </tr>');
    $("#myDynamicTable").show();
    }
```

On the click of a button, i'm calling the above function that adds a row to an html table. The table has columns itemName and itemQty which are filled in manually.

When i'm done adding any number of rows that i want and their column values, on a another button click, i want to read the values of rows in my table and save them to a database.

It would be nice to also ensure that both itemName & itemQty in a row have values and itemQty **must** be numeric.

```
 var arrItems = [];
$('#myDynamicTable').find('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var item = new GatePassItemsViewModel("", "", $.trim(row.find(".itemName").html()), $.trim(row.find(".itemQty").html()));
    arrItems.push(item);
});
```

I have tried the above code but both `$.trim(row.find(".itemName").html())` and `$.trim(row.find(".itemQty").html())` are returning an empty string.

Any one know how i can successfully read my table rows into my `arrItems` variable?

**Below is the table html**

```
 <table id="myDynamicTable" class="displaynone">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style='width:220px;'><b>Item</b></th>
                                            <th style='width:15px;'><b>Quantity</b></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why your `.html()` calls return nothing, but I can see a few reasons why you are having problems.

Main problem is that `row.find(".itemName").html()` will/should return the html the table cell contains, i.e. `<input... />`, while what you want is the value of that input element. So change to `row.find(".itemName input").val()` (i.e. target the input element and read its value) for both cases and you should be in better shape.

For validating the values, you can simply do something like:

```
...
var row = $(this),
  itemText = $.trim(row.find(".itemName input").val()),
  qty= $.trim(row.find(".itemQty input").val());

if(itemText.length === 0 || !qty.match(/\d+/)) {
  //Handle the problem of invalidity
}
```

This tests that, after trimming, `item` has a length greater than zero and that `qty` is an integer (consists exclusively of one or more digits).

Other issues/comments:

- Inside `AddRow()`, your table cells are nested somehow. You need to close the first cell before opening the second (and remove the final double `</td>`)
- The row `$.trim(row.find(".searchFirstName").html());` won't have any effect, as it only returns the trimmed value and doesn't change the variable or similar the value of which you are trimming.

Comment: this works, only problem now is it's reading the table header too, how  do i skip the header?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior : Put your `<th>` tags under `<thead><tr>` and put your custom rows inside `<tbody>`. And then append new rows  like `$('#myDynamicTable').find('tbody tr')`

Comment: Without much ado, it's also possible to just do: `$('#myDynamicTable').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {`. So no change to table structure. It'll skip the header row.